# Filling in online search query from application

Tags: android, html, http-post

For my android app, I am trying to do HTML scraping from this website:

http://www.trico.haverford.edu/cgi-bin/courseguide/cgi-bin/search.cgi

Essentially, my app has a button for each department, and for example if the user clicks "biology" , i want to search all the biology courses in the link and scrape the data from it.

Any tips. My intuition is to use a POST request where the key would be "department, and the value would be "biology"

Comment: Your key would be "srch_frz"

Answer (score 0):

"a button for each department" -- like organizing the websites you are interested in into groups of favorites? That's what a searchelerator does, try [DiCheetal](http://www.dicheetal.com/)